# Using EJS into input value doesn't show properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

Below is part of my node.js application's client code using EJS template. There is a input box and I want to show if user doesn't log in, show message into input box. and Also, input box should be unable too.

But It doesn't show properly, How can I display whole statement including space not just 'Need' but 'Need to Login' ?

```
<input type="text" <%= (isAuthenticated) ? '' : "value='Need to Login'" %> />

// view : 'Need
// It doesn't show after space
```

Comment: you're rendering this on node? i sounds like it's hitting the browser un-interpolated...

Comment: @dandavis No, It's .ejs code, I'm testing it in Google Chrome...

Comment: looking at the answer, which is probably right, it was kinda hitting the browser interpolated, but not in the way i though. do watch out for XSS if any of that content can ever be dynamic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In EJS `<%= foo %>` escapes HTML, while `<%- foo %>` does not.

In your case, `<%= "value='Need to Login'" %>` will render `value=&#39;Need to Login&#39;`, which isn't what you want.

Replacing `<%=` with `<%-` will do the trick.

In general though, be thoughtful when using `<%-`, especially when showing arbitrary strings or user input, as it could make you vulnerable to [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)).

Comment: It's working properly, and before sometimes I wondered the difference between `<%= and <%-`, now I got it, Thanks!